# Display country names in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

I have code like this that sets the map type to Terrain View:

```
map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));         
map.setMapType(G_PHYSICAL_MAP); //Terrain View
```

The `G_PHYSICAL_MAP` type used to display the country names, so Google must have changed this recently.  Is there a way to add the country names back?

This is how the terrain map  looks now without country names:
[Current Terrain View http://img413.imageshack.us/img413/3756/terrnoname.jpg](http://img413.imageshack.us/img413/3756/terrnoname.jpg)

This is how it was a few weeks ago:
[Terrain View with Country Names http://img13.imageshack.us/img13/2466/googlemapsterrain21.png](http://img13.imageshack.us/img13/2466/googlemapsterrain21.png)

Thanks.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the edits.  The maps do a great job in explaining the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The country names on the terrain map were part of the map imagery (before they disappeared). Unfortunately there seems to be no way to request different map imagery that includes country names.

The only option I see is to define your own map overlay on top of the terrain map, with all the country names. (Probably not practical and not easy).

**1st EDIT**: As suggested in a comment below, if you plan to add large overlays over the terrain map, you may want to use the open-source tool [MapTiler](http://www.maptiler.org/) (for Windows and Mac OS X). MapTiler will automate the tiling process for you, and in addition, once the tiling process is finished, it will generate a simple HTML viewer. If you are adding the name of just one country, you may want to use the [GGroundOverlay](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GGroundOverlay) instead. ([Google Demo](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/examples/groundoverlay-simple.html))

**2nd EDIT:** Note that this issue has been [acknowledged by a Google employee](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/maps/thread?tid=2e159d7bad0247e1&hl=en) on January 20th, and therefore you may want to consider waiting for a few days to see if it gets sorted automatically, before you commit your time to fix it.

**3nd EDIT:** This has been fixed a few weeks ago by Google.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, If I just needed to add one country's name and if I had the coordinates of that country, how would you do it?

Comment: For an individual country, I'd suggest placing the text in an ELabel that floats over the map rather than making tiles for each zoom level.

http://econym.org.uk/gmap/elabel.htm

Comment: Good Suggestion, Mike. The only issue with an ELabel is that it does not automatically zoom in/out with the zooming of the map.